# GHC 9 addLibrarySearchPath cannot find the file specified

Tags: haskell, configuration, filepath, ghc, ghci

I've installed GHC 9.0.1 on my Windows 10 machine, and when starting up GHCi, I get the following output (`[...]` represents omitted personal information):

```
> ghci
Loaded package environment from C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-9.0.1\environments\default
GHCi, version 9.0.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghc.exe: addLibrarySearchPath: C:\Program (Win32 error 2): The system cannot find the file specified.
ghc.exe: addLibrarySearchPath: C:\Users\[...]\Documents\Files\Haskell (Win32 error 3): The system cannot find the path specified.
ghc.exe: addLibrarySearchPath: C:\Users\[...]\Documents\Platform\8.6.3\mingw\lib (Win32 error 3): The system cannot find the file specified.
[ additional items omitted ]
```

It's looks like it's trying to find three separate paths, `C:\Program`, `Files\Haskell`, and `Platform\8.6.3\mingw\lib` instead of trying to find the single path `"C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.3\mingw\lib"`. Where can I find this configuration data and what do I need to do to fix this?